# Retrieve index and value of array selectbox

Tags: jquery

```
<?php foreach ($fruits as $fruit) { ?>
    <select name="fruits[]">
        <option value="">Apple</option>
        <option value="">Banana</option>
        <option value="">Orange</option>
    </select>
    <input type="text" name="quantity" value="" />
<?php } ?>

<script>
    $("select[input='fruits[]']").change(function () {
         // how to get the fruits array index 
         // how to get the fruits array value
    });
</script>
```

How to know the specific index and value selected in fruits array selectbox?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Something like:

```
$("select[name='fruits[]']").change(function () {
    var selectedIndex = this.selectedIndex,
        value =  this.value;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly the selector should be `select[name="fruits[]"]`. Then you can use `selectedIndex` on the DOM element. Try this:

```
$("select[name='fruits[]']").change(function () {
     console.log(this.selectedIndex);
});
```

Or for a pure jQuery method, use `option:selected`:

```
$("select[name='fruits[]']").change(function () {
     console.log($('option:selected', this).index());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<select name="fruits[]" id="fruit" onchange="calc()">
    <option value="">Apple</option>
    <option value="">Banana</option>
    <option value="">Orange</option>
</select>
<input type="text" name="quantity" value="" />
<script>
function calc()
{
    alert($("#fruit").prop("selectedIndex"));

}
</script>
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/FHh7r/)